# R - write.table overwrites file

Tags: r, file, write.table

My script reads in a list of text files from a folder. A calculation for all values in a few columns in each text file is made.
At the end I want to write the resulting data.frame into a new text file in a different location.
The problem is, that the script keeps overwriting the file it created before. So I end up with only one file (the last one that was read in).
But I don't get what I am doing wrong here. The output file name is different each time, so in my head it should produce separate files.

The script looks as follows:

```
 RAW <- "C:/path/tofiles"
 files <- list.files(RAW, full.names = TRUE)
 for(j in length(files)) {
   if(file.exists(files[[j]])){
     data <- read.csv(files[[j]], skip = 0, header=FALSE)
     data[9] <- do.call(cbind,lapply(data[9], function(x){(data[9]*0.01701)/0.00848}))
     data[11] <- do.call(cbind,lapply(data[11], function(x){(data[11]*0.01834)/0.00848}))
     data[13] <- do.call(cbind,lapply(data[13], function(x){(data[13]*0.00982)/0.00848}))
     data[15] <- do.call(cbind,lapply(data[15], function(x){(data[15]*0.01011)/0.00848}))
     OUT <- paste("C:/path/to/destination_folder",basename(files[[j]]),sep="")
     write.table(data, OUT, sep=",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, append = FALSE)
   }
 }
```

Comment: Check out the content of `OUT`. I don't think it is correct because you use the result from `list.files` with `full.names = TRUE` there.

Comment: `OUT` is correct. I am only using the `basename` from `files[[j]]`

Comment: But your `for` loop is not correct. It does only one iteration. It should be `for(j in seq_along(files))`.

Comment: Thats it! thx @Roland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `for` loop. `length(files)` just provides 1 value, namely the length of your `files`-vector, while I think you want to have a sequence with that length.
Try `seq_along` or just `for(j in files)`.

Comment: Thx! That was the problem. weird though that it worked for me in a different project the same way.